# Does Doctrine query builder use associations settings in entity metadata?

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

I have a User entity that has a many-to-one association with the entity License:

```xml
<entity name="...\User" table="users" repository-class="...\UserRepository">
  <many-to-one field="license" target-entity="License" fetch="EAGER">
    <join-column name="license_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
  </many-to-one>
  <field name="username" type="string" column="username" length="25" nullable="false"></field>
</entity>
```

I need to query in DQL with the Doctrine query builder as follows

```php
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('user')
  ->from('...\User', 'user')
  ->where(
    $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
      $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('user.license.id', '1234'),
      $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('user.username', 'test')
    )
  )
```

Result throws

```
Type: Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException

Message: [Semantical Error] Error: Class ...\User has no field or association named license.id
```

Why doesn't Doctrine consider metadata associations?
Am I missing something?

Comment: We discussed this directly, but using `foo.bar.baz.tab.tar` syntax doesn't really work in DQL. The reason is mostly that it's not implemented (it only works with embeddable types), because I think it makes quite a lot of sense for `to-one` association mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You could [join](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#line-number-5775ab09aefa638b14c776a733b4b61d2e324b74-33) the two tables and then filter by id in license table:

```
$qb->select('user')
   ->from('...\User', 'user')
   ->join('user.license', 'l')
   ->where('l.id = :var')
   ->setParameter('var', 1234)
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. I wanted to be able to query on my Entity without having to rejoin all the other associated entities as the associations are already defined in the metadata.